# Return one type based on the parameter instead of union

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that calls api and returns a data of for example array of strings.

```
async function getData(){
   const response = await fetchData()
   return response
}
```

so the function signature is fixed to `getData: () => string[]`
now I need to be able to pass some processor function that would transform the response.
Like

```
async function getData<T>(process?: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>) => T){
   const response = await fetchData()
   return process ? process(response) : response
}
```

but I get unknown type when this function is called

```
const result = await getData()
        ^
    unknown type
```

The desired result is to get as type `string[]` when process is not passed and return the `T` when `process` is there
also would be awesome to make `T` optional

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional types:

```
async function getData<T = string[]>(process?: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>) => T): Promise<typeof process extends undefined ? string[] : T> {
    const response = await fetchData()
    return (process ? process(response) : response) as any
}
```

Here's [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJAzAAsARKDKACgEoAueABRhwFssBnEAHg4xiyoA5gG0AugD4A3ACgZAegBUM0JFgIU6bHnhDC5SrQbM2nHnwHDx0leGhwkaTLnx6MBqNwAqEqjPgB8AAOLGAgHBwMVFTAFFAMAIIA7lBYGCDA3ABKhMgwqF4AnkE8GMUgOIgERGRxEhI08AC8EvBeNDL0TCzsXN42ivJyUByF6I5aLrr6cd7N8BaCopJUIThhEQD8UbGUiSlpGdm5+UUl3GUlldUkHvWNLW1dJr2l5ddrGxzwIAAe6ahgN80KBEIIMvBNgt+EtxPAGD54ABvfyBMB4PjwOAcIIYhBNeBQA4YG61Qw0WSBLEnfCrULhb5Qz4MqjY3GoLiNBhsvGNEaE1CFWQAXzk8nk8GQXAAtBxDjJ0RySb95m4PLRZIrMYVVTNDLsoM1WgBGABMAGYACwAVgpMiAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [function overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to infer the correct return type for your case:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#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)

```ts
declare function fetchData(): Promise<string[]>;

async function getData(): Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>>;
async function getData<T>(
  process: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>) => T,
): Promise<T>;
async function getData<T>(
  maybeProcess: ((data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>) => T) | undefined,
): Promise<T | Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>>;
async function getData<T>(
  process?: (data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetchData>>) => T,
) {
  const response = await fetchData();
  return process ? process(response) : response;
}

const r1 = await getData();
    //^? const r1: string[]

const r2 = await getData((data) => data.length);
    //^? const r2: number

declare const maybeProcess: ((data: string[]) => number) | undefined;
const r3 = await getData(maybeProcess);
    //^? const r3: number | string[]
```

---

Be sure to check the documentation for the compiler option [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes), which enables stricter handling of optional types.